# Delete word from phrase bash

Tags: bash

I would like to delete the word `blob` from phrase `$CHANGEDSITE`. but my code isn't working. Any suggestions?

```
#!/bin/bash
OLD=$1 ex. https://github.com/retep-mathwizard/imitate/blob/master/bjqx
NEW=raw.githubusercontent.com
CHANGEDSITE="${OLD/github.com/$NEW}"
REMOVEDBLOB="${CHANGESITE/blob/}"
echo $REMOVEDBLOB
```

Comment: You mean `$REMOVEDBLOB`?

Comment: sure, but when I try running, `REMOVEDBLOB` doesn't work.

Comment: give an example for `$1`

Comment: Ok. I did it!!!

Comment: I think it is just a case of typo `CHANGEDSITE` vs `CHANGESITE` without a `D`

Comment: http://www.shellcheck.net/# is a good site to catch such typos and avoid uppercase for your variable names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot a `D` in my variable, So CHANGESITE was nothing , hence the output being nothing

Answer (score -1):

You can use `sed`

```
OLD=https://github.com/retep-mathwizard/imitate/blob/master/bjqx
echo $OLD | sed 's/github.com/raw\.githubusercontent\.com/g' | sed 's/blob\///g'
```

The First sed change the url and the second remove the word `blob/`